# PHP ajax redirect

Tags: php

I have a sign in form.
When user enter wrong password or email the the php code is checking it
and the ajax gives him an alert some div id width some fade effect.

but the issue is that when the user put the right email and password i need him
to redirect to the index page, instead it shows me the index page inside the fade effect div.

How do i redirect the user to the index page ?

**Html code:**

```
<form action="./sign_in.php" method="post" id="form_sign_in">
       <input type="text" name="sign_in_email" id="sign_in_email">
       <input type="text" name="sign_in_pass" id="sign_in_pass">
       <input type="submit" name="connect" id="connect" value="Go">
</form>
```

**Sign in function:**

```
function sign_in_func($user_email, $user_pass) {

$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string($user_email);
$user_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($user_pass);

$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = '{$user_email}' AND user_pass = '{$user_pass}' limit 1";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];

        return TRUE;
    }
} else {

    return FALSE;
}
```

**sign is php code:**

```
if (isset($_GET['sign_in_email']) && !empty($_GET['sign_in_email'])) {

    $user_email = $_GET['sign_in_email'];
} else {

    echo 'Email is required <br>';

}

if (isset($_GET['sign_in_pass']) && !empty($_GET['sign_in_pass'])) {

    $user_pass = $_GET['sign_in_pass'];
} else {

    echo 'Pass is required <br>';
}


if (isset($_GET['sign_in_email']) && !empty($_GET['sign_in_email']) && isset($_GET['sign_in_pass']) && !empty($_GET['sign_in_pass'])) {

    if (sign_in_func($user_email, $user_pass)) {

        header("location: ../../index.php");
    } else {

        echo 'Wrong email or password';
    }
}
```

**The ajax code**

```
$('#form_sign_in').submit(function(){

var sign_in_email = $('#sign_in_email').val();
var sign_in_pass = $('#sign_in_pass').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'scripts/php/sign_in.php',
    data: { sign_in_email: sign_in_email, sign_in_pass: sign_in_pass },
    success: function(data){
        $('#signInFeedback').html(data);

        $('#signInFeedback').fadeIn('slow', function(){
            $('#signInFeedback').fadeOut(5000);
        });

    }
});
return false;
```

});

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can have an array with a `success` key set to `true` and an `html` key set to whatever you would display if `success` was not true, and then you can echo the JSON encoding, and parse it when it returns to your JS code.

Example:

```
//at top of code
$ret = [];

if (isset($_GET['sign_in_email']) && !empty($_GET['sign_in_email']) && isset($_GET['sign_in_pass']) && !empty($_GET['sign_in_pass'])) {
    if (sign_in_func($user_email, $user_pass)) {
        $ret['success'] = true;
    } else {
        $ret['success'] = false;
        $ret['html'] = 'Wrong email or password';
    }
}
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Then, in your JS:

```
success: function(data){
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    if(jsonData.success)
        window.location = 'your_redirect_url.php';
    else{
        $('#signInFeedback').html(jsonData.html);

        $('#signInFeedback').fadeIn('slow', function(){
            $('#signInFeedback').fadeOut(5000);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks its working ! but if the user entered wrong email or pass he gets the message: {"success":false,"html":"Wrong email or password"},

Comment: How to give him the message only Wrong email or password ?

Comment: Look at how to parse the json response